# How to get the Apache version

Tags: php

How do I get the Apache version?

Actually, I want to use the `setenv()` function in a PHP file, but I am not able to use that. It throws an error, undefined call to a function `setenv()`. It might be because of my Apache version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a nice script for it: http://snipplr.com/view/10881/get-apache-version/

The Apache version is contained in the predefined variable:

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']
```

You could also use [phpinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) to get much information about the server, including all $_SERVER variables, activated modules and disabled functions.

Comment: hello alexteg thanks for your reoly, i have used $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] but its only echoing 'Apache' & its not displaying version no. there. and i have also checked phpinfo() and used same function as given in your link but then also its not displaying any version no. Please suggest, am i making any silly mistake here ??

Comment: You can also try to use apache_get_version() http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-get-version.php

Comment: $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] = "Apache"

Comment: The server/version string returned here is dependent on the Apache `ServerTokens` directive (which can only be set in the main server config, governing the whole server). If this is explicitly set to `ServerTokens Prod` then you will only get the string "Apache" returned to PHP.

Comment: @alexteg - `$SERVER` is a nice array , but what's wrong with the simple built-in [apache_get_version()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-get-version.php) ? :- )

Comment: @ObmerkKronen apache_get_version() does not work for me on php 7.4.33

Comment: The php solutions did not work for me and it seems to depend on the server configuration if it works. As an alternative, log in via ssh to get a console and use the console command /usr/sbin/apache2 -V

Answer (score 6):

apache2 -v from terminal at least in mint 17

Comment: Thank you. /usr/sbin/apache2 -V      did the trick for me while the php based solutions did not work.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use the simple built-in php function `apache_get_version()`;

from [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-get-version.php) :

```
<?php
$version = apache_get_version();
echo "$version\n";
?>
```

*Edit* `Apr.2024`

This is a very old answer was not tested in new PHP versions 7,8 etc.nor new Apache vr. or configurations -  if someone tested please comment on results.

Comment: Note that `apache_get_version()` - depends on settings in the httpd.conf file (ServerTokens). So, in relation to the settings, it can simply return `Apache`, without any version/details...

Comment: @Andron - thanks, I did not know that - and actually never crossed such server :-) . it always worked for me. but from now on I will do as accepted answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the version of Apache:

```
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'];
```

Comment: Sadly, if ServerToken is set to "Prod", this just returns "Apache".

Answer (score 0):

The problem with apache_get_version() is that it depends on the settings on the server. Someone said it might return only "Apache" without the version but
it also can return an error message like the "function apache_get_version() doesn't exist". That is exactly the problem I have. So I would use $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'].

Correction: after trying  $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], it shows it won't work on every server. On my live website, I get only "Apache" as a result there is no guarantee to work for some of us.